# Finite Expectation for a non-negative random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, expected-value

I was told the following fact

For a non-negative random variable $X$, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}(X) < \infty  \ \ \ \text{if and only if} \ \ \ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(X \geq n) < \infty
$$

The only if part is clear to me, as
$$
\mathbb{E}(X) = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(X \geq t) dt \geq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(X \geq n)
$$

Yet, I have no clue how to approach the other side. Any hints are welcome, thanks!

Comment: Here I assume the random variable $X$ is continuous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integrating $P(X \ge \lceil t \rceil) \le P(X \ge t) \le P(X \ge \lfloor t \rfloor)$ yields
$$ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty P(X \ge n)
\le \int_0^\infty P(X \ge t) \, dt
\le \sum_{n = 0}^\infty P(X \ge n).$$